# multiple sequence file storing in java

Tags: java

I have sequence files which contains 60 columns and 182 rows. The sequences are normal DNA sequences like A, C, T, G and also contains - into it. What should I use to store and retrieve it java? Will it be useful to have String class concept or something else?

```
import java.io.*;
public class file 
{
public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception 
{
file fl=new file("FASTA71_5");
FileReader fr=new FileReader(fl);
BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);
String s;
while((s=br.readLine())!=null) 
{
System.out.println(s);
//System.out.println(s.replace("-","0").replace("G","1")); 
}
//System.out.println(s.replace("-","0").replace("G","1")); } } `enter code here`
```

Comment: I'd say that depends a whole lot on what you are planning to use it for...

Comment: What would `-` represent in such a file? Is there a structure (e.g. groups of sequences, patterns etc.) in the file or is it just a plain sequence of characters?

Comment: the file contains only 4 characters A,C,T,G and - .there are total 20 such files.and then i want to read all the files using one FileReader class.so how should i store them in array and using one filereader how should i get all the 20 files

Comment: Any coding effort so far?

Comment: import java.io.*;
public class file
{
 
 
  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception
   {
 file fl=new file("FASTA71_5"); 
      FileReader fr=new FileReader(fl);
      BufferedReader br=new BufferedReader(fr);

  
      String s;
      while((s=br.readLine())!=null)
      {
        System.out.println(s);
      
        //System.out.println(s.replace("-","0").replace("G","1"));
      }//System.out.println(s.replace("-","0").replace("G","1"));
      
   }
   
}

Comment: add that to your original question not as a comment.

Comment: As i want to read 20 files. there should not be 20 different file readers so how would i use one FileReader to read all the 20 files

Answer (score 0):

Use List. In each list element you should hold different sequence.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html